# R - Fill the arguments of a function in an ellipsis

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I have the following function :

```
ExampleFunction <- function(ListNumber1, ListNumber2)
{
  OutputData <- list()
  OutputData[[1]] <- rbind.fill(ListNumber1[[1]], ListNumber2[[1]])
  OutputData[[2]] <- rbind.fill(ListNumber1[[2]], ListNumber2[[2]])
  return(OutputData)
}
```

I want to improve this function introducing the possibility to use a variable number of arguments (i.e. lists in my example). Here is an attempt to do this but I don't see how to fill the arguments of `rbind.fill()`.

```
ExampleFunctionUpgrade <- function(...)
{
  Arguments <- list(...)
  OutputData <- list()
  VarNames <- paste0("List", seq_along(Arguments))
  for (i in 1:length(Arguments))
  {
    assign(VarNames[i], Arguments[[i]])
  }
  OutputData <- rbind.fill(???)
  return(OutputData)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to iterate over the columns *within* an `lapply` call that is to be bound together.

```
ExampleFunctionUpgrade <- function(...)
{
  Arguments <- list(...)
  OutputData <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(Arguments[[1]])) {
    OutputData[[i]] <- rbind.fill(lapply(Arguments, '[[', i))
  }
  return(OutputData)
}
```

If you don't like 'for loops' you can use two lapply calls.